# jQuery - Prevent Select Value from substituting text if no val is present

Tags: jquery

I have a select and the first option is normally "Please select blah, blah, blah" and has no value so when I do a check using the code below, I get a value of "Please select an option" for the first option. How do I prevent this?

See here for an example, https://jsfiddle.net/nvcc84st/

**CODE**

```
<select>
  <option>Please select an option</option>
  <option value="one">Option One</option>
  <option value="two">Option Two</option>
  <option value="three">Option Three</option>
</select>

$('select').on('change', function(){
  if ( $(this).val ) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can prevent this value from going to your JQuery code.  However you could just test for it and discard.

```
$('select').on('change' function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Please select an option") {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Or

```
$('select').on('change' function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "Please select an option") {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to leave the value = "" in the first option and in the JavaScript code you can control if the user has selected the first option

```
<select>
 <option value="">Please select an option</option>
 <option value="one">Option One</option>
 <option value="two">Option Two</option>
 <option value="three">Option Three</option>
</select>
<br>
<p>The selected value is <span>???</span></p>

<script>
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val() == ""){
        selectVal = "You must select an option";
    }
    console.log('selectVal = ' + selectVal);
    $('span').text(selectVal);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/nvcc84st/1/#&togetherjs=QTtMayqVO1):

```
<select>
<option value="0">Please select an option</option>
<option value="1">Option One</option>
<option value="2">Option Two</option>
<option value="3">Option Three</option>
</select>

<br>

<p>The selected value is <span>???</span></p>

$('select').on('change', function(){
var selectVal = $(this).val();
if(!parseInt(selectVal))
    {
  selectVal = "";
  }
  console.log('selectVal = ' + selectVal);
    $('span').text(selectVal);
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was to exclude the first option from the results. Your answer displays 0 when the first option is selected.

Comment: I have just provided a approach to reach the goal :)

Comment: !parseInt("0") is false So you should edit your code.

Comment: Please refer to the fiddle example provided there :). Neither it shows 0 on the selection of index 0 nor it shows any error with !parseInt("0")

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `.find()` `:selected` `:not()` `:contains()`
witch unselected option with `Please select an option`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvcc84st/3/)

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
var selectVal = $(this).find("option:selected:not(:contains('Please select an option'))").attr('value');
if(!selectVal)return console.log("not allowed");
  console.log('selectVal = ' + selectVal);
    $('span').text(selectVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to disable `first-child` option

Note: not recommended if you want to set option as placeholder and still available after selection.

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvcc84st/4/)

```
$("select option:first-child").attr("disabled",true);
```

or disable option `:contains` your text as you like.

```
$("select option:contains('Please select an option')").attr("disabled",true)
```

also disable option with `value="SPECIFIC_VALUE"`

```
$("select option[value='SPECIFIC_VALUE']").attr("disabled",true)
```